# I am not able to use mouse while executing the selenium test cases

Tags: selenium

Hi I am executing the selenium test cases .if I dont touch the mouse manually  while eecuting, the test case passes.if I move  the mouse my Login process fails and all the testcases followed by are failing, Basically I should be in a position to work while my test cases are executing. Please let me know if you know the solution.

Regards
Giri

Comment: That's strange. I can safely move the mouse, even click on some elements in the browser. Are you using the newest Selenium?

Comment: I would check if there is something weird with an onMouseOver event that might be fired so you are inadvertantly firing that.

Answer (score 2):

- Which OS and browser are you using?
- Can you show us a sample of your tests?
- Do you use any javascript tricks in your pages?
- Do you use any javascript tricks in your tests?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working with IE. There is an inherent problem with IE driver and does not perform very well when you fiddle around during test execution. My suggestion don't touch the mouse during the test execution.